# Acces my Apache Server through nginx and VPN

Tags: nginx, vpn, proxy, openvpn

My local system (127.0.0.1) is running an nginx server listening to port 443 and port 80, both TCP.

The system is connected to my router (94.1.2.3), which forwards all requests from WAN to the two ports. nginx forwards it to my apache web server on port 8080 in my local system. Everything working fine!

Now I need to connect my local system to a VPN/proxy server (180.4.5.6). I am connecting via an OpenVPN configuration, which works fine as well.

But the problem now is that requests from WAN don't reach my local system anymore.

The VPN/proxy provider opened port 49850 TCP for me.

My question is now: How do I need to configure nginx in a way that all traffic goes over the VPN and also requests coming back to my local machine?

I read something about upstream in nginx, but I am not sure, if that is what I need?

Edit: Here is a sketch to better understand what I have and what I need:

[image: network setup]